# Connect to database php

Tags: php, mysqli

What would be the correct way to connect to database ? I don't get errors but maybe my connect isn't used correctly I'm using mysqli 
Here is my code

```
 <?php 
 require_once("configur.php");

 $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, root, password, user);

 $query_image = 'INSERT INTO fun_table (images1, images2, images3, images4) 
values( "' . $_FILES['file1']['name'] . '",
        "' . $_FILES['file2']['name'] . '",
        "' . $_FILES['file3']['name'] . '",
        "' . $_FILES['file4']['name'] . '"
   )';


   if ($mysqli->query($query_image) === TRUE) {

   echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
   echo "alert('Upload successful!')";
   echo "</script>\n";
 } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
 }

    $mysqli->close();

   ?>
```

Comment: `localhost, root, password, user` those have been defined as constants, *right?*

Comment: and where's the form for this?

Comment: It should be `host, user, password, database`.

Comment: @aynber true but maybe their db is called `user`, who knows?

Comment: And use mysqli_error() along the way to actually check for errors.

Comment: ............bye

Comment: I just put localhost, user, root their for security reasons but everything is good if you like can post user and database

Comment: Please use
`echo mysql_errno($mysqli) . ": " . mysql_error($mysqli) . "\n";`
And check for problem.

Comment: You should use prepared Statments, because this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, root, password, user);
```

You need to define those or put them in quotes.

like:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'user123';
$password = 'helloworld';
$dbname ="testdatabase";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset($charset);
```

Comment: The OP commented that he replaced the values for security reasons when posting here.

Comment: Yeah I read that after posting, but since he replaced the values without quotes I could still imagine that´s the problem. But I will delete the answer if it isn´t.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use PDO for the connection, for example:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8mb4", "user", "password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```